# Size of families: Birth death immigration

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

The context of this problem is as follows. Starting from a population size of zero, immigrants arrive according to a homogeneous Poisson process with rate $\theta$. Once they arrive, immigrants start ''families" which are characterised as a linear birth and death branching processes, say with $N$ individuals at time $t$ and let $P(N(t)=n|N(0)=1)=g_{n}(t)$. Families evolve independently from each other.

Let $\xi_{n}(t)$ by the number of families of size $n$ at time $t$.We seek the probability generating function of $\{[\xi_{0}(t),\xi_{1}(t),\dots];t\geq0\}=\underline{\xi}(t)$, i.e.
\begin{gather}
G_{\underline{\xi}(t)}(\underline{s})=E(\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}s_{n}^{\xi_{n}(t)}).
\end{gather}
The result we wish to prove is
\begin{gather}
G_{\underline{\xi}(t)}(\underline{s})=\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}\text{exp}\bigg(-\theta(1-s_{n})\int_{0}^{t}g_{n}(u)\, du \bigg)
\end{gather}
that is $\xi_{n}(t)$ are independent Poisson random variables.

My initial attempt:  Conditioning on the number of immigrants $K(t)$, we have by the tower rule
\begin{gather}
G_{\underline{\xi}(t)}(\underline{s})=E_{K}(E(\prod_{n=0}^{\infty}s_{n}^{\xi_{n}(t)}|K)).
\end{gather}
Consider $g_{n}(t)$. For a given family with initial arrival time of $T_{i}$, the probability it is of size $n$ is $g_{n}(t-T_{i})$. As we have conditioned on the number of arrivals we have that each arrival time $T_{i}\sim U(0,t)$ by the ordered statistics property. Thus we have,
\begin{gather}
g_{n}(t-T_{i})=g_{n}(t-U_{i})=\frac{1}{t}\int_{0}^{t}g_{n}(t-u)du=p_{n}(t)
\end{gather}
for all families, which we note has no dependence on the arrival time. Therefore we have $K$ $i.i.d.$ families. The size of each family has no upper bound so we try and condition also on the $N(t)$ the total number of individuals in the system, so $N(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}i\xi_{i}(t)$, then the problem resembles a multinomial distribution. That is we will have $N$ objects to place into $K$ families. I am unsure of where to proceed from here with this argument and also not sure how to correctly condition on $N$ as surely $K$ is dependent on $N$ (if $N=0$ then $P(K=k)=\delta_{0,k}$). Or perhaps this approach is doomed and I should be looking to solve a Kolmogorov equation?

For those interested this is Theorem 1 from Simon Tavare's paper "The Genealogy of the Birth,
Death, and Immigration Process ". It has been annoying me for some time so helpful hints would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in the answer, this is simply the splitting property of the Poisson process.